# react-svg-pan-zoom: Problem with production version (serve build)

Tags: reactjs, svg, zooming, create-react-app, svgpanzoom

I'm using [react-svg-pan-zoom](https://github.com/chrvadala/react-svg-pan-zoom) component from an application created using create-react-app, everything works fine as long as I do not build.
When I execute:

```
npm run build
serve -s build
http://localhost:5000/
```

I see a blank page and this is what i see in console log:
[image]

Something strange seems to happen when I produce the minimized version. Has anyone already had a similar problem?

Answer (score 0):

The post that solve the problem is on [GitHub project page](https://github.com/chrvadala/react-svg-pan-zoom/issues/140#issuecomment-472424720)

The browser field in react-svg-pan-zoom's package.json is set to use the UMD bundle. CRA's build process (ala webpack) is using that field as a hint and end up pulling the UMD bundle to include in your final app build. I believe React only works with es6 classes. The quick-fix here is to change your import statements to explicitly use the ES bundle in this package. For e.g. change

```
import { UncontrolledReactSVGPanZoom } from 'react-svg-pan-zoom'
```

to

```
import { UncontrolledReactSVGPanZoom } from 'react-svg-pan-zoom/build-es'
```

Thanks to [lionkeng](https://github.com/lionkeng)